# How can i convert string to long?

Tags: java, string

i have added code and error below, please change the below code correctly.
i got NumberFormatException, how can i solve it.

Code:

```
try{
String balance1 = childNode.getChildText("Balance1");//For input string: "00000162968518794 "
System.out.println(balance1);
long ledgerBalance = Long.valueOf(balance1);
accountSummaryList.setLedgerBalance(ledgerBalance);
System.out.println(ledgerBalance);
}catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
nfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "00000162968518794 "
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at mbank.eai.adaptor.accountsummary.AccountSummaryAdaptor.getAccountSummaryList(AccountSummaryAdaptor.java:68)
at mbank.eai.adaptor.accountsummary.AccountSummaryAdaptor.main(AccountSummaryAdaptor.java:108)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "00000162968518794 "
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at mbank.eai.adaptor.accountsummary.AccountSummaryAdaptor.getAccountSummaryList(AccountSummaryAdaptor.java:68)
at mbank.eai.adaptor.accountsummary.AccountSummaryAdaptor.main(AccountSummaryAdaptor.java:108)
```

Comment: [Trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) your string before converting it to `Long`.

Comment: it should work,thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error suggests, you have an extra white space at the end. Change this line:

```
String balance1 = childNode.getChildText("Balance1");
```

To this:

```
String balance1 = childNode.getChildText("Balance1").trim();
```

Answer (score 6):

Your input string contains a trailing space. Trim it first.

`balance1 = balance1.trim();`

or

`long ledgerBalance = Long.valueOf(balance1.trim());`

Answer (score 4):

Your input string is not trimmed. The exception message states that your input was

```
"00000162968518794 "
```

with an additional white space at the end. Try trimming the input as in:

```
long ledgerBalance = Long.parseLong(balance1.trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

That's simple.

```
Long.parseLong("786")
```

Answer (score 0):

its soo simple. Just watch the code

```
try{

String balance1 = "0000000162968518794 ";

System.out.println(balance1);

long ledgerBalance = Long.parseLong(balance1.trim());

System.out.println(ledgerBalance);

}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
{

    System.out.println("exception");
nfe.printStackTrace();

}
```